# Bridges between maths and physics: the $\tau=2\pi$ constant

Tags: conventions, integration, calculus

[disclaimer: I am not a math or a CS major, this is probably an easy question for most people on Physics SE.]

I just read the [tau manifesto](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto) explaining - according to its [author](http://www.michaelhartl.com/) - the various advantages of the τ constant defined as :

> $\tau=2*\pi$

My question is about [section 3, "Circular area, the coup de grâce"](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto#sec-circular_area) : Michael Hartl gives several formulas, summarized [in table 3](http://tauday.com/tau-manifesto#table-quadratic_forms) :

> - Distance fallen   : $y(t)=\frac{1}{2}.g.t^2$
> - Spring energy   : $U(x)=\frac{1}{2}.k.x^2$
> - Kinetic energy  : $K(v)=\frac{1}{2}.m.v^2$
> - Circular area   : $A(r)=\frac{1}{2}.τ.r^2$

Beyond the fact that this formulas *may* be easier to memorize for students since they're all very similar (~ $\frac{1}{2}.constant.x^2$), I'd like to know if there's a structural reason for such a similarity. E.g. has the law of the "distance fallen" something to do with the area of a circle ?

We can find such a similarity in the expression of the gravitationnal attraction and of the Coulomb's law, [as pointed here](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-explanation-for-the-similar-formulas-of-Gravitational-attraction-and-Coulombs-law?share=1). The discussion leads to the following conclusion :

> [...] the flux of field on the surface of a volume is equal to the
>   amount of source (charge or mass) enclosed by the surface. Since we
>   live in 3D space with 2D surfaces, it necessitates the $1/r^2$ force
>   law.

In other words :

> [...] both electromagnetism and gravity obey Gauss's law, which says that the amount of force over a closed surface containing a charge/mass is exactly proportional to that charge/mass.
>
> But why do both electromagnetism and gravity obey Gauss' law? The answer is surprising. The two forces are transmitted by particles called photons and gravitons, respectively. Both of these particles are massless, and it turns out that this is exactly why the forces obey Gauss's law.

Does such an explanation apply to the examples given by Michael Hartl ?

Comment: That's because $\int axdx = \frac{1}{2} ax^2 + C$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see a function that looks like:

$$ y = \tfrac{1}{2}kx^2 $$

there's a good chance it came from integrating the function:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = kx $$

For example your distance function comes from integrating the velocity $v = at$:

$$ y(t) = \int v\,dt = \int at\,dt = \tfrac{1}{2}at^2 $$

The spring energy function comes from integrating the force $F=kx$:

$$ V(x) = \int F\,dx = \int kx\,dx = \tfrac{1}{2}kx^2 $$

The area of a circle isn't obtained in this way. If you rotate a radius $r$ by an infinitesimal angle $d\theta$ then the area traced out is the area of a triangle with height $r$ and base $rd\theta$ so it's:

$$ dA = \tfrac{1}{2}r^2d\theta $$

Integrate this from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$, i.e. in a full circle, and you get:

$$ A = \pi r^2 $$

So there is no common ground with the mechanics equations.

For the record: few working physicists give a stuff about switching from the symbol $\pi$ to the symbol $\tau$. Those who agitate about this have far too much free time on their hands.

Comment: A more rigorous way to obtain the area of a circle is to do the integral $4\int_0^r\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: Of course you can get the area of a circle in a similar way. For a very thin ring the area is simply its circumference on the thickness $dA=2\pi r dr$, so the full area is given by $A=\int_0^R 2\pi r dr$. Of course both of us simply skip one of the integration in $A=\int_0^R dr \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi r$.

Comment: @OON: true   :-)${}{}$

Comment: (The advantage of my method is that it doesn't have $\pi$ or $\tau$ in it.)

Comment: @0celo7: yes, but you have to know how to do the integral